# Ninject - bind a parameter in a nested binding

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

Coul someone please tell me how to fix the error the below code creates and pass proper value to the  "x" paramter in constructor of "B"?

I'm getting: Additional information: Error activating string

```
    interface IA { }

    class A : IA
    {
        public A(IB b) { }
    }

    interface IB { }

    class B : IB
    {
        public B(string x) { }
    }

    class Main() {
        IKernel n = new StandardKernel();
        n.Bind<IA>().To<A>();
        n.Bind<IB>().To<B>();
        IA a = n.Get<IA>(new ConstructorArgument("x", "BLE"));
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried

```
IA a = n.Get<IA>(new ConstructorArgument("x", "BLE", true));
```

(true flag => inherited) ?

You can either inherit the `ConstructorArgument` (if it's not inherited it only applies to the type directly resolved - in this case `A`), or you can adapt the binding of B and add a parameter (`ConstructorArgument`) to it.